# PDFBox - convert image to PDF, PDF resolution

Tags: java, pdf-generation, pdfbox, acrobat

I am using PDFBox v2 to convert jpg images to PDF. JPG image is already on the filesystem, so I just pick it up and convert it to PDF. Below is my code

```
public void convertImgToPDF(String imagePath, String fileName, String destDir) throws IOException {
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(imagePath);
        BufferedImage bimg = ImageIO.read(in);
        float width = bimg.getWidth();
        float height = bimg.getHeight();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(new PDRectangle(width, height));
        document.addPage(page);
        PDImageXObject img = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(imagePath, document);
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
        contentStream.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        contentStream.close();
        in.close();
        document.save(destDir + "/" + fileName + ".pdf");
        document.close();
    }
```

This code does the conversion just fine. However, I have observed the following in converted PDFs

1. When I open a converted PDF, it opens very slowly (in Acrobat reader). It seems as it PDF is opening pixel by pixel. If I open any other PDF, it opens just fine.
2. The default size in acrobat reader is shown to a smaller value (like 15% or 24%, screenshot attached) for converted PDFs. Even though it covers 100% of the screen (15% sould have implied that I see a much smaller image, but that is not the case). When I change the size to 100%, I see a highly blurred image which is much larger than the actual image and I have to scroll left/right and top/down to see the complete image.

Both these observations make me feel that for some reason the PDF that is getting generated is a much higher resolution than it should have been. Would  that be a fair statement? If so, how can I correct this?

[image: PDF size]

**EDIT**
Attached the JPG image which is being converted to PDF. When I open the PDF, it shows a size of 25.9%. This image was clicked on iPad.

[image: Image to be converted to PDF]

Comment: Please share the image in question to reproduce the issue.

Comment: `new PDPage(new PDRectangle(width, height))` is not a good idea, the sizes are in page units, 1 unit = 1/72 inch.

Comment: Thanks @TilmanHausherr, so what should I be using instead?

Comment: I have attached a sample JPG image

Comment: @kayasa I've deleted my earlier comment, it is more complex and I'm confused myself now. I can't really answer, but now I think, page size and image scale should be seen separately. I.e. 1) decide on a page size, 2) decide on a scale for image display so that it fits. For your example, dividing by 3 and scaling the image by 3 worked nicely for some reason. With an A4 paper size by using `new PDPage()`, `contentStream.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width / 6, height / 6);` leaves some blank area.

Answer (score 0):

There is an overloaded `drawImage()` method to do that

```
contentStream.drawImage(PDImageXObject, float x, float y)
contentStream.drawImage(PDImageXObject, float x, float y, float height, float width)
```

By specifying explicit width and height on `contentStream.drawImage()`, this can be achieved. For instance if you want to show the image 4 times smaller but still retain the same resolution, it can done using

```
scaleDownRatio = 0.25;
pageSize = PDRectangle.A4;

# this will draw image at bottom left corner
PDImageXObject pageImageXObject = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, bitmap);
contentStream.drawImage(pageImageXObject, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth() * ratio, bitmap.getHeight() * ratio)

# to center it you can use something like
contentStream.drawImage(pageImageXObject, (pageSize.getWidth() - bitmap.getWidth() * ratio) / 2, (pageSize.getHeight() - bitmap.getHeight() * ratio) / 2, bitmap.getWidth() * ratio, bitmap.getHeight() * ratio)
```

Note: in your case, the image wouldn't still fit in even after scaling it to one-fourth the size; You can get the scale factor by

```
float widthRatio = bitmap.getWidth() / pageSize.getWidth();
float heightRatio = bitmap.getHeight() / pageSize.getHeight();
scaleDownRatio = (widthRatio<heightRatio)? widthratio:heightRatio;
```