# PDFBox: Writing HD images to PDF

Tags: android, pdfbox

I am trying to convert image shot using cameraa to A4 PDF

```
    // Read image width and height
    float imageWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
    float imageHeight = bitmap.getHeight();

    // Read page width and height ignoring the margins
    float pageWidth = PDRectangle.A4.getWidth() - (margin_left_right * 2);
    float pageHeight = PDRectangle.A4.getHeight() - (margin_top_bottom * 2);

    Log.d("Image Resize", String.valueOf(imageWidth) + " x " + String.valueOf(imageHeight));
    Log.d("Image Resize", String.valueOf(pageWidth) + " x " + String.valueOf(pageHeight));

    # Image: 4160.0 x 3120.0
    # Page: 575.27563 x 821.8898

    Log.d("Image Resize", String.valueOf(requiredRatio));
    Log.d("Image Resize", String.valueOf(newImageWidth) + " x " + String.valueOf(newImageHeight));

    # Required ratio: 0.13828741
    # After scaling: 575 x 431
```

Problem is image with size `4160 x 3120`, after getting resized to `575 x 431`, looks very pixelated.

How do PDFs solve this problem in general? Is there a way to say `4160 x 3120` at `600 dpi` when writing using `contentStream.drawImage()`?

---

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39948870/3125070) also supports the fact that if written without resizing on pages of size equal to the height and width of the image, OP could only see the images at 15%, how should that be scaled down without loss of quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an overloaded `drawImage()` method to do that

```
contentStream.drawImage(PDImageXObject, float x, float y)
contentStream.drawImage(PDImageXObject, float x, float y, float height, float width)
```

By specifying explicit width and height on `contentStream.drawImage()`, this can be achieved. For instance if you want to show the image 4 times smaller but still retain the same resolution, it can done using

```
scaleDownRatio = 0.25;
pageSize = PDRectangle.A4;

# this will draw image at bottom left corner
PDImageXObject pageImageXObject = LosslessFactory.createFromImage(document, bitmap);
contentStream.drawImage(pageImageXObject, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth() * ratio, bitmap.getHeight() * ratio)

# to center it you can use something like
contentStream.drawImage(pageImageXObject, (pageSize.getWidth() - bitmap.getWidth() * ratio) / 2, (pageSize.getHeight() - bitmap.getHeight() * ratio) / 2, bitmap.getWidth() * ratio, bitmap.getHeight() * ratio)
```

Comment: Your answer to your question is the same as your answer to somebody else' question you linked to. WTF??

Comment: there's no way to specify DPI directly, but using this, you can tweak it such that if you input DPI you get the image printed shrunk without downsampling

Comment: @TilmanHausherr btw that was **me** who posted this answer after I wrote it here as that would be of help to that person too..